# How to prevent git gc running automatically during fetch

Tags: git

I want to avoid running `git gc` when I initiate a `git fetch`. It is not just because of its time consumption but also having lots of unlinking failures. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable that function with

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```